# How to execute WSL from Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is installed on my system and it works just fine. But from my Delphi code it does not work at all.

I'm trying to write code to execute "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe" to run any Linux command (for testing I try to execute `wsl echo foo` or `uname`). But it just doesn't work and it claims the file would not exist.

So far I have a function that uses `CreateProcess` to execute some command and read the output from stdout. This works fine as long as I am executing Windows applications. I.e. I can do `cmd /C echo foo`. More specifically:

```
CreateProcess(PChar('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'), PChar('/C echo foo'), nil, nil, true, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo);
```

This simply gives me "foo".

But whenever I try to execute wsl it claims that the file does not exist. It does or at least seems to exist when I check it. I can open it in a hex editor. So this really is a file, even if windows provides it as some kind of virtual file or whatever it could be. I understand that "echo" is built-in and not a real file. But in that case wsl should run and give me "echo: command not found". So if some file actually doesn't exist, it would be wsl.exe.

`CreateProcess` returns false and `GetLastError()` gives me 2, which stands for "The system cannot find the file specified." That would be wsl.exe missing, which is not the case.

I tried the same by executing the compiled exe file directly (not inside Delphi) and I tried the same with "run as Admin". Same result.

I can use Java (i.e. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wsl uname")`) to execute wsl and read its output without any problems. So this should be possible. Only in Delphi it does not work.

Comment: Isn't this just the classic 32/64 bit file system redirector issue?

Comment: The API does not lie. If it says it can't find the file, then it really can't find the file. Please show your actual code that is trying to execute WSL.

Comment: There's a good chance that it's an issue about 32/64 bit. We are still using some old libraries without 64bit support. I will create a simplistic new project to test this.

Answer (score 0):

It really was just the redirection. All I have to do is disable it like so:

```
function Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(Var Wow64FsEnableRedirection: LongBool): LongBool; StdCall;
  External 'Kernel32.dll' Name 'Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection';
function Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(Wow64FsEnableRedirection: LongBool) : boolean; StdCall;
  External 'Kernel32.dll' Name 'Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection';

// ...

function TSomeClass.Execute(const ApplicationName, CommandLine: String; out Output: String): boolean;
var 
  WOW64reditrection : LongBool;
  // ...
begin
  if not Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(WOW64reditrection) then
    raise Exception.Create('Could not disable Wow64FsRedirection');
  try
    // ...
  finally
    if (not Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(WOW64reditrection)) then
      raise Exception.Create('Could not revert Wow64FsRedirection');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't do that if at all possible. Solve the problem some other way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what would be the reason to avoid this?

Comment: In case any code runs that does require redirection. Other solutions include using a 64 bit process, or using `C:\Windows\Sysnative`.